# Can't release the ID3DX11Effect pointer?

Tags: graphics, directx, directx-11, direct3d, direct3d11

I use Effect framework in my demo.

here are my defination in header file

```
    ID3D11Buffer*                   m_pVertexBuffer;
    ID3D11Buffer*                   m_pIndexBuffer;
    ID3D11InputLayout*              m_pInputLayout;

    ID3DX11Effect*                  m_pFx;
    ID3DX11EffectTechnique*         m_pTechnique;
    ID3DX11EffectMatrixVariable*    m_pFxWorldViewProj;
```

I release them as follow

```
void HillsDemo::UnLoadContent()
{
    if (m_pVertexBuffer) m_pVertexBuffer->Release();
    if (m_pIndexBuffer) m_pIndexBuffer->Release();
    if (m_pInputLayout) m_pInputLayout->Release();
    if (m_pTechnique) m_pTechnique->Release();
    if (m_pFx) m_pFx->Release();
}
```

[image: error picture]

then I run the demo,when I close the demo window, there is an error which means HillsDemo has stopped working.Why?Then I delete the line`if (m_pFx) m_pFx->Release();`,there is no error. So is releasing the `m_pFx` make the error?

I view the documents of Effect11 https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11/wiki/Effects-11, there are on the document:

The following types are now derived from IUnknown: ID3DX11EffectType, ID3DX11EffectVariable, I3DX11EffectPass, ID3DX11EffectTechnique, ID3DX11EffectGroup. Note that these objects do not follow standard COM reference-counting rules and they are released when the parent ID3DX11Effect is released. This is mostly to simplify use of Effects 11 from managed languages.

Does it means that I should only release the `m_pFx` rather than release both `m_pFx` and `m_pTechnique`? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using the latest version of Effects 11 from [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11) rather than the legacy DirectX SDK copy based on your reference to the project wiki.

You should really look at using [ComPtr](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr) instead of raw pointers to COM objects. In the case of Effects 11, you'd just use them for `ID3DX11Effect` instances. You should stick with 'raw pointers' for `ID3DX11EffectType`, `ID3DX11EffectVariable`, `I3DX11EffectPass`, `ID3DX11EffectTechnique`, and `ID3DX11EffectGroup`. Don't bother calling `Release` on these raw pointers as the lifetime controlled by the `ID3DX11Effect`.

Something like:

```
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> m_pVertexBuffer;
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> m_pIndexBuffer;
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11InputLayout> m_pInputLayout;

Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3DX11Effect> m_pFx;
ID3DX11EffectTechnique* m_pTechnique;
ID3DX11EffectMatrixVariable* m_pFxWorldViewProj;

void HillsDemo::UnLoadContent()
{
    m_pVertexBuffer.Reset();
    m_pIndexBuffer.Reset();
    m_pInputLayout.Reset();
    m_pFx.Reset();
    m_pTechnique = nullptr;
    pFxWorldViewProj = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: thank you, there is no error if I use ComPtr. But If I use raw pointer,  the problem has still not been solved as long as I release the m_pFx. It is so confusing.

Comment: I just use the `D3DX11CompileEffectFromFile` function,just like this: hr = D3DX11CompileEffectFromFile(L"color.fx", nullptr, D3D_COMPILE_STANDARD_FILE_INCLUDE, shaderFlags,0, m_pd3dDevice, &m_pFx, &errorBlob);   ,is it wrong?